# Trying to understand the fallacy in my inductive reasoning regarding this conclusion?

Tags: logic, induction, abduction

Consider the following statements:

- Anna told you she failed her physics midterm.
- Anna hasn't been in physics class since the teacher graded the exams.
- Anna has been in sociology class, which meets right after physics.

Can we not reach the conclusion *inductively* that **Anna dropped physics.**?

I understand inductive reasoning is based on past experiences. From past experiences, we try to predict the future or draw some conclusions.   So from past experience, we know that students who fail midterms, has not been taking (physics) class for a long time while taking immediate classes( sociology in this case)-- with a high probability will drop (physics) class.

But [this article ( under Abduction)](https://sites.google.com/a/oroville.wednet.edu/philosophy/lesson-3-how-to-argue---induction-abduction)  says that it can not be inductively concluded that Anna dropped physics class based on the given premises.
The author says that it can be concluded only through Abduction. I am unable to understand this and I think as shown above it can be concluded inductively.

Is there any fallacy in my argument? Kindly help me understand. thanks

Comment: I think, considering how is written the test of the article, that the author expects you to use only the premises they provide. In order to use induction you need knowledge about past similar events, but this knowledge is not provided in the example. You are right that, had you had such knowledge you could have used induction.

Comment: Seems like she just stopped showing up. Claiming she dropped the class requires facts definitely not in evidence.

Answer (score 1):

The term 'induction' or 'inductive reasoning' is often used rather loosely, and there is no general agreement on its relationship with abduction. Some accounts treat deduction, induction and abduction as separate and exclusive categories, others regard abduction as a specific kind of reasoning that depends on deduction and induction, others again (including Gilbert Harman) regard induction as a species of abduction.

In the article you reference, induction is treated as a form of reasoning in which a probable conclusion about the future is based on an observation of past events together with an assumption of relevant similarity between the past and future. As you are probably aware, there are philosophical objections to this idea. Abduction is presented in the article as a process of arriving at a good explanation of an event by eliminating bad explanations.

Either way, the reasoning depends on past experience. In your example, you are being asked to find an explanation of some observed events that are listed. Given those events, the most plausible explanation is that Anna dropped physics. The reasoning conforms to the pattern of: here is something that we would like to explain, and here is our best effort at a plausible explanation, so the reasoning is abductive. An inductive approach (going by the account in the article) would be more along the lines of: most people who fail a midterm exam in some subject and switch classes are found to have dropped that subject; Anna failed a midterm exam and switched classes, so probably Anna dropped physics.

The difference is really not that great, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.